# gradle assembleRelease uses wrong key/certificate

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, keytool, signing

I have a gradle-based android project and trying to generate a release apk. However, it seems that somehow gradle is picking up the wrong key/cert.

This is what I have in build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("mykey.jks")
        storePassword "mypass"
        keyAlias "mykey.key"
        keyPassword "mypass"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebugBuild false
        runProguard true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

And after running

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

and taking out META-INF/CERT.RSA from inside the .apk I run the following:

```
keytool -list -keystore mykey.jks
```

and

```
keytool -printcert -v -file CERT.RSA
```

but they produce output with different certificate fingerprints. Trying with a certificate from another apk signed with the same key (but not with gradle) yields the correct certificate fingerprint.

Gradle seems to be picking up the keystore fine (changing the password or location or alias makes it stop working).

I'm puzzled since I don't want to release something to the store signed with an unknown key and then not be able to update it. I don't have a debug key explicitly defined in gradle.

**UPDATE:** This has something to do with the keystore. Trying the same gradle code with a fresh keystore and key works fine. This problematic keystore was imported from a pkcs#12 format (.p12 file). Using Intellij or jarsigner works fine with this keystore though, it's just the gradle code that has a different output - and it seems only the certificate generated from the key is different.

Comment: if you have older apk of same signed with certificate try to install that in device. If it replaces that it is perfect. I am using the same from long time nothing wrong in signing .

Comment: this is a brand new app so there are no older apks. If I build this with IntelliJ's "generate signed apk" the two generated apks are not signed with the same cert (getting INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES when trying to install one on top of another). Doing the certificate fingerprint dump indicates the one generated by IntelliJ uses the right certificate (can't upload to google play though because it's debuggable).

Comment: try clean and then build once. use this for clean `gradle clean` .

Comment: already tried, no change.

Comment: Its surprising because exactly same thing is working perfectly for me here. Which version of gradle are you using ? try commenting out your signing configs and try to build from both command and intellij they should throw some error.

Comment: if you read the original post you'll notice I already tried that - "changing the password or location or alias makes it stop working".

Comment: I've started a session in mail group for this question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/Z1ghmNPd8bw).

Comment: Try erasing everything in ~/.gradle/caches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution here was to start with a fresh key. The previous key had been imported from a PKCS12 format and I think that somehow caused the gradle code to generate a different certificate than jarsigner.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while building signed .aab file with gradle.
It has to do with gradle caching issue.
I just restarted my gradle daemon threads running in my system and clean gradle cache.

```
./gradlew --stop
./gradlew clean
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

And it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was not aware I am using debug keystore file for release. In project/android/app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // <-- need to be changed with
        //the line below
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```