# Why my Facebook SDK HashKey continuously changed?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-login

I sometimes got `Invalid key hash. The key hash bMWwxx...8BE does not match any stored key hashes ...` error to login with Android Facebook SDK.

I added given key hash to my Facebook developer page and it worked well. But currently fifth hash key is added now.

Is it normal to be changed? or is there any reason to make it change? There's no change to `.keystore` file for months but hash key was renewed twice.

Comment: Are you only building apks from a single computer? Are you generating any release apks (vs. debug apks)?

Comment: @MingLi // good question. I got the problem especially when I merged with git-pull my colleague's work. But I checked `.keystore` is not changed.

Comment: @MingLi // And I do gradle assembleRelease to generate apk.

Comment: It's possible that gradle assembleRelease is not using the right key from your keystore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493951/gradle-assemblerelease-uses-wrong-key-certificate